# UITextView or UIWebView: How to display pages of a simple editable TXT file

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sdk, uiwebview, uitextview

**All I want to have is a full-screen simple text editor. However, I don't want the scrolling component, but rather let the user flick through the pages (instead of scrolling).** So I need to import or open a TXT and then format it by braking it down (e.g. by dividing its contents to 10 lines per screen/page).

My question is how I will display the txt? UITextView is scrollable (even though I can disable this in IB)... I did not find any method for UIWebView to let it format my contents on different 'pages' or screens.

**Where will I need to start?** Ideally I'd need some sample code. All the samples for UIWebView do not tell me anything about how to format editable text on several pages.

So all I really want is an UITextView which is not scrollable and opens up a new page/screen if I run out of space on the first page/screen.

Thanks for any help to get me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing first ...... there is no particular method to achieve this

1.You need to break your single string into multiple strings, to do that you can use

```
  int pageNumber; // suppose this keep track of on what page you are
  int count; //suppose this keep track of how long string your one screen support
  NSString* completeString; //suppose this is your string
  NSRange range = NSMakeRange(pageNumber * count, count);
  NSString* temp = [completeString substringWithRange:range];
```

2.Now instead of using UITextView (if you don't want user interaction ) you should use UILable
just change the property of UILabel (this one is of your interest)

```
UILabel* myLabel; //suppose this is that label
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //this will chage your label to go multyline.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't see how I can account for the lines on the screen. If I only count how long my string can be, I have a value of how many characters it is long and not how many LINES it takes up on the screen...

Comment: Also, I need the ability for the user to interact, so I need to stick with UITextView.

Comment: Don't you think it's best to go with the option as suggested by Gnuchu who told me to put the UITextView into an UIScrollView and then enable pagingEnabled? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by putting your UITextView into a UIScrollView and setting pagingEnabled on the UIScrollView to YES.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me into that direction. That makes perfect sense!

Comment: Hmm... just tried this, but it doesn't work. According to the documentation, pagingEnabled only causes the scroll views to be stopped on MULTIPLES of the scroll view's BOUNDS when the user scrolls. This does't give me the effect that if you have, for example, two screens of text that you can flip from one to the other with a swiping gesture (like in a book)...

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial by Matt Gallacher. It may help: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html